# ExtJS4 Changing data store parameters

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, javascript-framework

If I have a data store on a grid like so:

```
store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: [{
        name: 'id'
    }, {
        name: 'filename'
    }
    // other fields here ...
    ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'http://myniftyurl.com/blah',
        simpleSortMode: true,
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            totalProperty: 'total',
            root: 'result'
        },
        extraParams: {
            'limit': Ext.get('itemsPerPage').getValue(),
                'to': Ext.get('to_date').getValue()
            //  other params
        }
    },
    model: 'Page',
    remoteFilter: true,
    remoteSort: true
});
```

The 'limit' and 'to' value will change based on user input, therein lies the problem. The data store keeps using the original parameters instead of the new inputs. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using the MVC pattern? (i.e. is there a controller behind this?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally load my grids manually by executing the store.load() in the controller.

That way prior to it I can change the store's params like so:

```
//getForm() retrieves the Ext.basic.Form (from Ext.panel.Form)
var params = this.getForm().getValues();

//Write over
grid.getStore().getProxy().extraParams = params;

//load
grid.getStore().load();
```

I'm using buffered grids which required a decent amount of rework to get completely working in 4.0.7.  But that should work for you.

Another options is to use a `beforeload` listener but I'm not sure if changing the extraParams by then will do anything.  You may be able to modified the Ext.data.Operation object that gets passed to the event handler?

Let me know how that works out for you.

Good luck!

Comment: Manually calling store.load() works, thanks! what I'm realizing is that the big problem is with the buttons on the paging toolbar. How can I change the click events so that I can manually call load like you've demonstrated above?

Comment: For the paging toolbar, it should use the params that were last set to the store.  So you wouldn't want to change the parameters except through your filter you have made.  Am I wrong?

Comment: You're right! I just had to make sure that the parameters are updated in the beforeload, and it works perfectly. Thanks again John!